# Having Trouble with LOAD DATA INFILE command likely because of inexperience

Tags: mysql, csv

I've got a database with a very simple structure:

```
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ngram | varchar(64)         | NO   | UNI |         |                |
| count | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

As you can probably guess I'm importing the Google Web Ngrams stuff into this database.

The file is a tab delimitated CSV file with the ngram first then the count second.

Here's the command I thought would work:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'vocab' INTO TABLE ngrams_copy FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (ngram, count)
```

But I get an error saying:

```
Row 9558923 doesn't contain data for all columns
```

But I thought that since I was specifying the ngram and count columns that I was telling it that this didn't matter.

Would love any help since I'm out of my area of expertise with this.

Comment: What data does the complaining row contain?

Comment: Good question, a backslash and then the count. Perhaps the backslash is confusing things?

Comment: Very likely. Might want to give other rows a quick look, or search for any other 'stray' backslashes.

Comment: How would I go about still allowing a back slash to work? Double back slash or something like that?

Comment: Perhaps, you'd have to try it and see. Is that backslash in the 'ngram' position? If so, maybe it could have quotes `'\'` ... I would try to eliminate any garbage from the import to avoid any "garbage in, garbage out" factors, and other matters that might cause the data load to break. At least determine and fix how the backslashes are being added to the import if you are finding many occurrences.

Comment: Yes it's one of the ngrams. I'll try double back slashing any back slashes and see where that gets me.

Comment: Double back slashes solved the issue. Thanks or working it out with me though I should have figured that out on my own. :P

Comment: No problem, it's a learning experience!  :-) ... For matters such as that, at least have a look at the point where the error complains, especially for most data import issues.